# Cancellation of Outlook AppointmentItems

Tags: outlook-addin, appointment

I have a strange issue regarding the cancellation of an Appointment/Meeting in a C# Add-In. Of course it is possible that I do not handle the events correctly. This is how I do it:

- Register Event `BeforeDelete` on AppointmentItem which may have 0 to n recipients
- My goal is to handle the deletion of an AppointmentItem *with* and *without* a cancellation message:

  - **No recipients:** ask for confirmation before deleting in `BeforeDelete`. After Outlook has left the `BeforeDelete` event handler, the item will be deleted from the calendar. I use `Cancel = true` to prevent a deletion, if the user declines the confirmation.
  - **1 to N recipients:** Outlook will enter the `BeforeDeletion` as usual. The main difference is now that there won't be a deletion but the Inspector opens ready for you to send the cancellation message to the recipients. In this case I want to ask the user for confirmation after he clicks on "Send Cancellation".
- **Problem:** *How do I differentiate between meetings with no recipients which get deleted directly and those who need a cancellation message to be sent?*
- **Here the strange issue:** When I create an AppointmentItem with 1 recipient, I already have different behaviors on different Outlook installations (both 2010, one with a Gmail account the other one is connected to a company Exchange Server): The Outlook with the Gmail account tells me that `AppointmentItem.Recipients.Count` is **1**, the Outlook with the Exchange Server tells me there are **2** recipients (*including myself!*). Why is that??